# Getting pseudo-elements for TweenLite animation

Tags: jquery, pseudo-element, gsap

I use TweenLite for animation and need to animate pseudo-element `::before`.     `CSSRulePlugin` gives such opportunity, as:

```
var rule = CSSRulePlugin.getRule(".myClass:before"); //get the rule
TweenLite.to(rule, 3, {cssRule:{color:"#0000FF"}});
```

My problem is in a different way of getting the element - I am accessing it as element of array inside iteration loop:

```
for (let i = 0; i < this.items.length; i++) {
   let before = CSSRulePlugin.getRule($(this.items[i]) + ':before');
            TweenLite.to(before, .5, {
                opacity: 1
            } );
}
```

I've tried also:

```
let before = CSSRulePlugin.getRule(this.items[i] + ':before');
```

And in both cases got error:

> Cannot tween a null target.

**Q:** how to write proper selector to get pseudo-element?

Here also my footer with all required scripts:

```
> <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/2.0.1/plugins/CSSRulePlugin.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/2.0.0/plugins/CSSPlugin.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/2.0.0/easing/EasePack.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/2.0.0/TweenLite.min.js"></script>
```